# Replace part of form element attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to replace a part of the name attribute with a new value. This value is dependent on the original value. The name attribute has a value of: timeslots[timeslot_1][start]

1. How do I increment the value 'timeslot_1' to 'timeslot_2' and replace the original value with this one?
2. The cloneElm consists of two types of elements (input and select) - I want to be able to capture both elements in my loop.

The code I have so far:

```
$(cloneElm).children('span').children('input').each(function(id) {
        var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace('timeslot_1', 'timeslot_2');
        $(this).attr('name', newName);
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'm not sure I'm on the right track, as I'm a little confused by your question but here is a stab at it.

```
$(cloneElm).children('span').children('input').each(function(id) {
        var mynumber = parseInt((($(this).attr('name')).split("_"))[1]);
        var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace('timeslot_' + mynumber, 'timeslot_' + (mynumber + 1));
        $(this).attr('name', newName);
    });
```

After reading some of the other posts this could get cleaned up like this

```
$(cloneElm).find(':input').attr('name', function(i, name) {
  var mynumber = parseInt(name.split("_")[1]);
  return name.replace('timeslot_' + mynumber, 'timeslot_' + (mynumber + 1));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this more general approach with [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is what you're after:

```
$(cloneElm).find(':input').attr('name', function(i, name) {
  return name.replace('timeslot_1', 'timeslot_2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can pass a function as the second argument to *attr()*, eliminating the need for *each()*.
- In order to select both *input* and *select* elements, you need to adjust your selector accordingly.
- Finally, you can supply a regular expression and a function to the *replace()* method too.

Here is an example combining the above:

```
$(cloneElm).children('span').children('input, select').attr("name", function () {
    return this.name.replace(/timeslot_(\d+)/, function ($0, $1) {
        return "timeslot_" + (+$1 + 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more generic, this just increments the number on all select and input fields name attribute.

```
$(cloneElm).children('span').children('input, select').attr('name', function(i, name) {
  if ((var result = name.match(/\d+$/)) && result)
    return name.replace(/\d+$/,parseInt(result)+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* (as many people have pointed out) use string splitting and regular expressions to do this, but in my opinion that's kind of messy and arguably unnecessary.

If you're using jQuery 1.4.3 or above, you can use the HTML5 `data` attributes to store data in your HTML elements for later use[1].

I'll let you decide how best to select the element you need, but something like this should provide the function you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function inc_timeslot(elem) {

    // calculate our next timeslot however we need to
    var timeslot =  $(elem).data("timeslot");

    timeslot += 1;

    // set the attribute
    $(elem).attr("name", "timeslot_" + timeslot);

    // and update the data attribute for next time
    $(elem).data("timeslot", timeslot);


}

</script>

<!-- ... -->

<input name="timeslot_1"  data-timeslot="1">
```

1. In earlier versions of jQuery, you could use the jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to set the data, but this means you'll probably need to use in-line `script` tags.